# What are the best uses for Go Imaginary Literals?

Tags: go

It would be fine for me if the code below returned ***true***.
Since it has not, what are the best uses for this [feature](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Imaginary_literals)? What am I missing?

```
a := 10.52i
b := 10i

fmt.Println(a == b)
//false
```

Comment: If you're not joking, "imaginary" numbers are used often in science and engineering. They're not imaginary in the sense of not existing; they're just different from the real numbers.

Comment: Why would 10 equal 10.52 in floating point, whether real or imaginary?

Comment: *"what are the best uses for this feature?"* -- large areas of mathematics that deal with [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Comment: Based on the comments so far, I realized what I am missing is [Math knowledge] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number).

Comment: I would like to understand why the downvotes. If lack of knowledge deserves it, so all questions in StackOverflow should be downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Tashi, @Arkku and @axiac's comments, I realized that I am missing [Math knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) to understand this feature.